# Drag and drop ghost image mispositioned in Chrome

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

In Firefox, the tip of the mouse cursor appears at the exact middle of the ghost image.

In Chrome, and other Chromium based browsers, the tip of the cursor appears at **about** one third of the ghost image in both directions.

I suspect it has something to do with using 125% DPI scale on my Win7 system, but I am not sure. Any ideas?

```js
let dragImage = document.getElementById("drag-image");
let draggable = document.getElementById("draggable");

draggable.addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", null);
  e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragImage, 50, 50);
});
```

```css
#drag-image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
#draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="drag-image"></div>
<div id="draggable" draggable="true"></div>
```